# Prevent manually added libraries from being deleted by ndk-build

Tags: android-ndk

I have a project which is reusing a native library (libocr.so) pre-compiled and for which I don't have source files.
I manually put the library on libs/armeabi of my project and everything works perfectly.

Then I needed to create a new native library to the same project. I put my source code as weel as the Android.mk file in my jni folder and I build it with ndk-buld command.
The library is build and placed in libs/armeabi folder, but libocr.so (the one manually added) is automatically deleted from there...
How can I prevent libocr.so from being deleted?

Here is my Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libyuv
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ycrcbutils.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Thanks in advance for any help, Luca.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

...ok I found the answer by myself...
according to `ndk/docs/PREBUILTS.HTML` I changed my `Android.mk` like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_MODULE    := libyuv
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ycrcbutils.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)


# Add prebuilt libocr
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libocr
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libocr.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and placed a copy of my libocr.so under jni folder of my project.

Comment: Note the optional use of TARGET_ARCH_ABI, eg: LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libfoo.so

Comment: @NateS i love you so much.

Comment: @lviggiani i am facing similar issue and i have only .so file not .cpp and when i run the program it give error stop abborted